# How can I concatenate a range of cells according to adjacent value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, array-formulas, apple-numbers

In the following table, I'd like to concatenate the numbers of column B, according to string in column A:

[image: My table]

For example, all the numbers adjacent to `XX` would be copied to another cell in this format: `12, 12, 21, 23, 31, 32`.

I can manually concatenate the whole of column B using:

```
=ArrayFormula(concatenate(B2:D&", "))
```

But I need to split those values according to column A.

I can manipulate this data in Google Sheets, Excel or Numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(A1:A5), TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(transpose(UNIQUE(A1:A5))=A1:A5,B1:B5&",",""),,500000)))})
```

I hope your rows don't exceed 500000 and you don't have blanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A1:A9 = "XX",B1:B9,""))
```

As an array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

In Google Sheets:

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(B1:B9,A1:A9="XX"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that works for the range in the example. 

My table has thousands of rows, and I'd like to be able to achieve the same effect without manually specifying the string (eg `XX`). 

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, just replace the `"XX"` with a cell reference that holds the criteria you want.

Comment: Thanks again - so I want to concatenate `B:B`, then split the array into groups defined in `A:A`.

I tried `=JOIN(", ",FILTER(B:B,A:A=A:A))` but it just concatenated all values in column `B`. I want to have a series of arrays, rather than one long array.

Comment: Copy and paste Column A then remove the duplicates.  Then reference each cell with the formula.

Comment: Sorry, this is what I have now -
https://imgur.com/a/egutm - did you mean something different?

Comment: Not sure how google does the remove duplicates.  You would have wanted to copy A to C then do remove dups on C then put the formula in D.